# Outer apply vs inline query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Should there be choice between these two queries or any one can be used?

**Inline Query**

```
select 
       *,
       (select count(*) from t2 where Id=t1.RefId) as Count
from t1
```

**Outer apply**

```
select 
       *,
       c.Count
from t1
outer apply (select count(*) as Count from t2 where Id=t1.RefId) c
```

Comment: They are basically the same thing and should have the same execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

As Gordon states in his comment above, the Outer Apply as used in your code should have the same or a similar execution plan as the non outer apply query.  However, if you have multiple scalar subqueries like this:

```
select 
       *,
       (select Min(Val) from t2 where Id=t1.RefId) as Minimum
       (select Max(Val) from t2 where Id=t1.RefId) as Maximum
       (select count(*) from t2 where Id=t1.RefId) as Count
from t1
```

where the only difference between the sub queries is returned value, then an outer apply query could be more efficient:

```
select 
       *,
       c.Minimum,
       c.Maximum,
       c.Count
from t1
outer apply (select Min(Val) as Minimum,
                    Max(Val) as Maximum,
                    count(*) as Count,
               from t2 where Id=t1.RefId) c
```